# The controller for URI is not callable

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm working on Symfony 2 and create a new action named "newAction" in "UserController":

```
/**
 * @Route("/new", name="user_new")
 */
public function newAction()
{
    if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        return $this->forward('RikkeiLunchOrderBundle:User:access_denied.html.twig', Array());
    }
}
```

I want to check if the user has role Admin to create a new user. But I got this error(when user is not an admin):

**The controller for URI "/user/new" is not callable.**
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException

Below is access_control and role_hierarchy in security.yml:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/user/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/user/list, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/user/delete, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/order/dish/new, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/API/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }

role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
```

Please help if you know the solution!

Comment: Can you post your security.yml file as well

Comment: Your access controll is already checking if your user has the role_admin, you shouldnt need to do it in your controller as well. The error is likely called due to a bad role check system. How are you implementing roles in you application?

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake when edit my question and forgot to remove the line "- { path: ^/user/new, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }". Ofcourse I don't need to check in the controller if I set the access_control like that. What I actually want is using another 'access_denied' page instead of the default one in symfony.

Comment: Role check system was installed using 'the Entity Provider' follow this tutorial: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html

Comment: You can override the default access denied page within symfony without using that check. Check out: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html  Now if you are looking to send users to multiple different access denied pages then I understand doing it the way you are.

Comment: did you defined `/** @Route("/user") */` for your controller?